# Sizing a List and referencing variable positions in a List C#

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

Needed to store many varbiables and at first went with an array, but I had errors when I tried to resize the amount of positions in an array with a separate variabe. Looked online and people said, better use a List.

I have but very confusing to use. Trying to use it logically but I'm just not getting it.

So I set up my list:
`public List<int> TESTValues = new List<int>(10);`

And to me logically, there should be a list on 10 positions but there isn't, it's empty. Only does it add a variable if I use: `TESTValues.Add(1);` which only adds 1 new variable in the next available position which is 1 when it should be position 11 right?

Let's say I would somehow get a list of 10 variables, how would I then reference a variable in position 8 of the list, even update it? I tried to use something like: `TESTValues.IndexOf(8) = 40;` sadly that does not work.

Anyone have a good understanding of these Lists and how I could get to use them? Explain them? Was expecting a List to be simpley than an Array, seems the other way round right now.

Comment: Read the documentation. [`LIst<int>(10)`]((https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1__ctor_System_Int32_)  results into creating list of integer with initial capacity of 10 elements, that you will have to add. Once you add elements to the list, you can refer to it by index. For e.g. `list = new List<int>(); list.Add(10); list.Add(20); list.Add(30); Console.WriteLine(list[2]);` where 2 is the position in the list where it will find 30.

Comment: It's `Capacity` not `Count` please read the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.capacity?view=net-5.0#remarks

Comment: Great. `Debug.Log(TESTValues[1]);` works but I still don't understand the list declaration. I can declare it with 10 and add 5, but when I run the code I only have 5 not 15.

Comment: Nice, I can also use `TESTValues[1] = 10;` to update variables. Some great stuff. Still confused on the size declaration part. Do I declare `public List<int> TESTValues = new List<int>();` and on a separate line do something like `TESTValues.Capacity(10);`?

Comment: No. You don't need to declare size when creating a list. It will expand to as many elements as you add to it.

Answer (score 2):

#### [Capacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.capacity#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Capacity) != Size ([`Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.count#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Count))

> Gets or sets the total number of elements the internal data structure **can hold without resizing**.

The initial **capacity** given to the constructor has only one purpose: Immediate allocation.

Usually by default a `List<T>` starts with an initial **capacity** of `4`. Under the hood it simply stores the values in an array.

Then every time you add elements and the new size would exceed the **capacity** then the underlying array is copied into a new array with double of the original size (= **capacity** of the list).

---

The **"size"** (= [`Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.count#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Count) of the list) only grows by adding elements!

> Gets the number of elements contained in the `List<T>`.

---

Now the only way to initialize a list with already 10 elements is by using another collection like e.g.

```
var yourList = new List<int>(new int[10]);
```

of course this requires the allocation of an array => work for the GC but if you do this only once probably not very problematic.

or using `Linq` you could also do

```
using System.Linq;

...

var yourList = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 10).ToList();
```